# Pytorch customize weight

Tags: pytorch

I have a network

```
class Net(nn.Module)
```

and two different weights `w0` and `w1` (concatenate weights of all layers into a vector). Now I want to optimize the network on the line connecting `w0` and `w1`, which means that the weight will have the form `theta  * w0 + (1-theta) * w1`. So now the parameter I want to optimize is no longer the weight itself, but the `theta`.

How can I implement this? In Pytorch, how can I define the parameter to be `theta`, and set the weight to be form I want. To be specific, if I create a new class

```
NetOnLine(nn.Module)
```

how should I write the `forward(self, X)` function?

Comment: look at `nn.Module`'s `register_parameter` method and in `nn.Parameter` docs

Answer (score 1):

You can define the parameter `theta` in your net as an `nn.Parameter`. You'd define the forward function the same way as normal - pass the data through the layers or operations you want and then return it.

Here's a minimal example, where I train a "network" to learn to multiply a Tensor by 2:

```py
import numpy as np
import torch


class SampleNet(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(SampleNet, self).__init__()

        self.theta = torch.nn.Parameter(torch.rand(1))

    def forward(self, x):
        x = x * self.theta.expand_as(x)  # expand_as() to match sizes
        return x


train_data = np.random.rand(1000, 10)
train_data[:, 5:] = 2 * train_data[:, :5]
train_data = torch.Tensor(train_data)

sample_net = SampleNet()

optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(params=sample_net.parameters())
mse_loss = torch.nn.MSELoss()

for epoch in range(5):
    for data in train_data:
        x = data[:5]
        y = data[5:]

        optimizer.zero_grad()
        prediction = sample_net(x)
        loss = mse_loss(y, prediction)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

    print(f"Epoch {epoch}, Loss {loss.data.item()}")
print(f"Learned theta: {sample_net.theta.data.item()}")
```

which prints out

```
Epoch 0, Loss 0.03369491919875145
Epoch 1, Loss 0.0018534092232584953
Epoch 2, Loss 1.2343853995844256e-05
Epoch 3, Loss 2.2044337466553543e-09
Epoch 4, Loss 4.0527581290916714e-12
Learned theta: 1.999994158744812
```

Comment: But the structure of my network is very complex. It may contain many layers, including Linear layer and Conv2d layer, and is treated as a black-box. Also it seems that all the weights of these layers are automatically regarded as parameters. So how can I turn them into just number and add my own parameter theta.

Comment: You can access the layer weights directly with ```layer.weight.data```, and multiply them by theta as you want. It's not clear to me exactly how you want to use the weights and theta with your model, so it's hard for me to say. Maybe this discussion will help you with accessing the weights: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-extract-learned-weights-correctly/4295